# Get the exact posotion of a listview item when selected

Tags: android

Need some correction in my code, am trying to pass three strings from a list item to the next activity using intents. Every thing works fine but the problem is i can't figure out how to get the exact position of the list item so that i only pick the contents of that list item and carry them to my other activity.

ActivityOne.java

```
int ctryId;
    mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try {

        mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

        for (int i=mComments.length() - 1; i>=0; i--) {
            JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

            ctryId = c.getInt(TAG_COUNTRY_ID);
            if (ctryId == 2){

                ListItem item = new ListItem();

                item.setRegionId(c.getString(TAG_REGION_ID));
                item.setRegionName(c.getString(TAG_REGION_NAME));
                item.setCountryId(c.getString(TAG_COUNTRY_ID));

                listItems.add(item);
            }

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegionsOfVisit.this, LocationsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Regions_of_visit_region_id", item.getRegionId());
                    intent.putExtra("Regions_of_visit_region_name", item.getRegionName());
                    intent.putExtra("Regions_of_visit_country_id", item.getCountryId());
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }

        // notify data changes to list adapater
        regionsOfVisitListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: item.getRegionId(). Here can you access this? Can you compile this line without error.

Comment: Amsheer, i can compile without error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your coding structure but below snippet might help you.

Assuming that your listview is made up of items of ListItem objects and the Adapter takes the list of ListItem objects.

Then your onitemclicklistener may work like as given below:

```
ArrayList<ListItem> list;
//fill your list with data
ListAdapter mAdapter = new ListAdapter(context,list);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

ListItem item = ListItem item = list.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegionsOfVisit.this, LocationsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Regions_of_visit_region_id", item.getRegionId());
                    intent.putExtra("Regions_of_visit_region_name", item.getRegionName());
                    intent.putExtra("Regions_of_visit_country_id", item.getCountryId());
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

One of the change is here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RegionsOfVisit.this, LocationsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Regions_of_visit_region_id", item.get(position).getRegionId());
                    intent.putExtra("Regions_of_visit_region_name", item.get(position).getRegionName());
                    intent.putExtra("Regions_of_visit_country_id", item.get(position).getCountryId());
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Another change is make this as global

```
  ListItem item = new ListItem();
```

Comment: i can not use get() because its not in my ListItem class